# Python enumerate list setting start index but without increasing end count

Tags: python

I want to loop through a list with a counter starting at zero but with the list starting index at 1 eg:

```
valueList = [1, 2, 3, 4]
secondList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

for i, item in enumerate(valueList, start=1):
    print(secondList[i])
```

The code fails with an index out of range error (I realize this is because i ends at the length of the list -1 plus the start value and that python lists are zero indexed so using i in this way to call the ith element in another list is not valid). The following works but the addition of the test for i greater than zero looks un-pythonic.

```
valueList = [1, 2, 3, 4]
secondList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

for i, item in enumerate(valueList, start=0):
    if i > 0:  
        print(secondList[i])
```

Enumerate is not the right choice, is there another way?

Comment: what are you trying to do? Why are you skipping the first element of the secondList?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I agree, iterating over one list to get items in another is probably not a great strategy, I'll reassess the design.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It sounds as if you want to *slice* the list instead; still start `enumerate()` at one to get the same indices:

```
for i, item in enumerate(valueList[1:], start=1):
```

This then loops over `valueList` starting at the *second* element, with matching indices:

```
>>> valueList = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> secondList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> for i, item in enumerate(valueList[1:], start=1):
...     print(secondList[i])
... 
b
c
d
```

In this case, I'd just use `zip()` instead, perhaps combined with `itertools.islice()`:

```
from itertools import islice

for value, second in islice(zip(valueList, secondList), 1, None):
    print(value, second)
```

The `islice()` call skips the first element for you:

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> for value, second in islice(zip(valueList, secondList), 1, None):
...     print(value, second)
... 
2 b
3 c
4 d
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not enumerate, and neither the `start` argument, but the fact that when you do `start=1`, you're enumerating from `1` to `valueList+1`:

```
>>> valueList = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> secondList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> for i, item in enumerate(valueList, start=1):
...     print(i)
...     print(secondList[i])
...     print('----')
... 
1
b
----
2
c
----
3
d
----
4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

So of course, when you try to access `secondList[4]` there's no value available! You might want to do:

```
>>> for i, item in enumerate(valueList, start=1):
...     if i < len(secondList):
...         print(secondList[i])
... 
b
c
d
```

That said, I'm not sure what you're exactly attempting to achieve. If you want to skip the first value of `secondList`, that might be a solution, even though not the most efficient one. A better way would be to actually use the slice operator:

```
>>> print(secondList[1:])
['b', 'c', 'd']
```

If you want to iterate over a list using *natural* enumeration (instead of *computer*'s one), i.e. starting from `1` instead of `0`, then that's not the way to go. To show *natural* indexes and use *computer* indexes, you just have to do:

```
>>> for i, item in enumerate(valueList):
...     print("{} {}".format(i+1, secondList[i]))
... 
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
```

Finally, you could use `zip()` instead of enumerate to link contents of both lists:

```
>>> for i, item in zip(valueList, secondList):
...     print('{} {}'.format(i, item))
... 
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
```

which will show each value of `valueList` attached with the value of `secondList` at the same index.

Answer (score 1):

If your collections are generators, you might be best off doing:

```
for i, item in enumerate(valueList, start=1):
    if i < 1:
        continue
    print(secondList[i])
```

or to modify Martijn Pieters's great answer,

```
from itertools import islice, izip
for value, second in islice(izip(valueList, secondList), 1, None):
    print(value, second)
```

this way data are lazily loaded.

Answer (score -1):

Or without using the start-parameter, you can do an if-comparison i > 0. That way you also don't have to deal with the list+1 index error at the end:

```
for i, item in enumerate(valueList):
    if i > 0:
        continue
    print(secondList[i])
```